# Finding a limit of a two variable function: $f(x,y)=\frac {\sin(x^2-xy)}{\vert x\vert} $

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, closed-form

I have this exercise but not sure if I'm doing it right
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {\sin(x^2-xy)}{\vert x\vert} $$

I assume $\frac {\sin(x^2-xy)}{\vert x\vert}\le\frac {1}{\vert x \vert} $
then the limit goes to infinite and does not exist.

Is that correct? Or there is some Taylor to use, or some direction to search? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

> Your conclusion is not correct, you have just 'proved' that a real number $c$ is such that $c\le \infty$, you can't say that *necessarily* $c \to \infty$.

One may recall that, as $u \to 0$,
$$
|\sin u| \le |u|
$$ giving here, as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$,
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x^2-xy)}{|x|}\right|\le \frac{|x^2-xy|}{|x|}=|x-y| \to 0.
$$

Comment: I see, I thought about that onestly. So this prove tha the limit exist and is zero? Because for wolframalpha the limit does not exist (maybe wolframalpha it's wrong then?)

Comment: Clearly this proves that the limit does exist and is $0$.